# About template inheritence

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following classes:
// the concreteIterator.h

```
template<class Item>
    class concreteForwardItr : public iterator<Item>
{

public:
    concreteForwardItr(){}
    concreteForwardItr( List<Item> *theList){
      //  this->iterator();
        targetList = theList;
        currentPos = 0;
    }

  void first(){
        currentPos = 0;
    }

   Item CurrentItem() const {
    // return targetList->
     if(!IsDone())
     {
        return targetList->get(currentPos);
     }

  private:
    List<Item>* targetList;

    //keep track of current position
    long currentPos;
}

//iterator.h
template <class Item>
class iterator{
public:
    virtual void first() =0;
     virtual Item CurrentItem()  = 0;
}
```

but the compiler complains: undefined reference to 'iterator::iterator()'

But I don't even call that function. I know the compiler will generate a default one for the list class. Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: The default constructor of `iterator` is implicitly invoked by `concreteForwardItr`'s constructor. Just wondering, is `iterator` defined in a library external to your program? It seems the error is being raised by the linker.

Comment: @faranwath no, iterator is just another file I have written within in the same project. From the effective c++ I know most compilers are not going to look at the base class if you inherit from a template base class. I try to use the method suggested within the book but still no luck happens.

Comment: Did you try explicitly calling `iterator`'s constructor?

Comment: @faranwath yes, and I also try: using iterator::iterator on the top of the class.

Comment: Are you by any chance creating a full specialization of iterator somewhere in the project that you aren't showing us here?

Comment: @NathanMonteleone I don't think so. the concreteIterator is the only class that inherits the iterator interface.

Comment: Ok.  It might help if you pasted how you are actually instantiating concreteIterator.

Comment: The instantiations of `concreteForwardItr` will be abstract classes since you don't override `iterator::CurrentItem`. Is this intended? (`concreteForwardItr::CurrentItem() const` does not override `iterator::CurrentItem()`. Use the `override` "keyword" if you can.)

Comment: you realize that C++ already *has* iterators, yes? And their interface is ar less broken than what you're trying to copy from C#/Java.

Comment: @jalf: it's arguable, Eric Niebler (from Boost fame) [has much to say](http://ericniebler.com/2014/02/16/delimited-ranges/) about the ways C++ iterators are broken when expressing the concept of ranges.

Comment: @MatthieuM. sure, C++ iterators certainly aren't perfect, and I am familiar with the criticisms of them, but I'm pretty sure the solution isn't the utterly crippled C#-style iterators.

Comment: @dyp I guess you are right, concreteForwardItr::CurrentItem() const is not overriding the iterator::CurrentItem, which makes the concreteForward abstract. Would you please make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @jalf yeah I know about it but I am a beginner of the world of template and I want to play around it. When I read the design pattern iterator, I want to implement it by using template class.

Comment: @NathanMonteleone I just use the normal way, new concreteForwardItr<Item>() to instantiate the object. The problem is the const in the concreteForwardIterator makes it abstract. Please take a look at dyp's comment. Many thanks for the help

Comment: So this fixed your problem? What a weird error message..

Comment: yes, just by getting rid of the const. I am using QT. The error message is not informative at all.

Comment: @user2984297 That's fair. :) If the objective is learning about templates, I would suggest throwing out the inheritance and every virtual function, and exploring how far you can get without it. That's where you'll see what templates can do. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's put this in the right order:

```
template <class Item>
class iterator{
public:
    virtual void first() = 0;
    virtual Item CurrentItem()  = 0;
}


template<class Item>
    class concreteForwardItr : public iterator<Item>
{

public:
    concreteForwardItr(){}
    concreteForwardItr( List<Item> *theList){
      //  this->iterator();
        targetList = theList;
        currentPos = 0;
    }

  void first(){
        currentPos = 0;
    }

   Item CurrentItem() const {
    // return targetList->
     if(!IsDone()) // what is `IsDone`?
     {
        return targetList->get(currentPos);
     }
   // where's the closing brace?

  private:
    List<Item>* targetList;

    //keep track of current position
    long currentPos;
}
```

*One* problem with this is that `concreteForwardItr::CurrentItem` does not override `iterator::CurrentItem`, because the former is `const` but not the latter. You should always use the "keyword" `override` when you want to override a virtual function (if your compiler supports it):

```
Item CurrentItem() const override
{ /* ... */ }
```

This would have produced a compiler error along the lines of *error: function does not override any base class virtual function*.

To make `concreteForwardItr::CurrentItem` override `iterator::CurrentItem` adjust the const-qualification of either one. Which one you should adjust is a design decision; if the interface declares that member function as `const`, the implementation cannot change that.

I've commented on two other possible problems in the first code block. Note that in the source file (.cpp), the class template `iterator` should occur before `concreteForwardItr` ("the right order").

---

You might want to consider renaming this class, as it fulfils the C++ concept of a *range* rather than that of a C++ *iterator*.

Virtual functions typically have a runtime overhead, and iterators/ranges are often used in loops. That might be one of the reasons why the Standard Library (and boost ranges IIRC) don't use a class hierarchy design for their own iterator/range classes, but rather unrelated classes fulfilling some abstract concepts, combined with generic algorithms. The algorithms are also decoupled from the class design of the iterator, they only require the concept.

Comment: good comments there. I was copying part of my codes to make this more clear but unfortunately it makes more confusion. So for the last part of your answer, it is exactly what I am trying to learn, the iterator pattern. But I should just use concrete class to get rid of the overhead of virtual function to make it more efficient.